# Eclipse trouble - getting standalone file to run in project

Tags: java, eclipse

I've always despised having to create a project in order to run a single Java file, which apparently I have to do in Eclipse.  I finally figured out how to add a file to my project, but once I do that and I try to run the file, I get the following error: `Editor does not contain a main type`

What am I doing wrong?  What all do I need to do to get an existing .java file to compile and run in Eclipse (apparently I have to add it to a project, which I now know how to do)?

Comment: One of these [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113729/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type) should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I tried opening and closing the project like several people there suggested, and am now getting a different error: Selection does not contain a main type

Comment: Hmm. Does the class you're trying to run have a main method like ```public static void main(String[] args) {```? Which you're running as the Java application.

Comment: Yes, it does have a main method.

Comment: Try [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6757677/792238)

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!